# Exchange the position of button in android

Tags: java, android

So what I want to achieve is to change the position of my buttons. this is my sample picture:

**Note:** 

 My buttons have background drawable, for example sake, I just uploaded without the background images on buttons. 

**Default**
[image: de]

**When shuffled:**

[image]

So this is the code I'm working on:

```
        List<Integer> objects = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        objects.add(0);
        objects.add(1);
        objects.add(2);
        objects.add(3);
        objects.add(4);

    // Shuffle the collection
    Collections.shuffle(objects);

    List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();

    buttons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.bObject1Stage2_1));
    buttons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.bObject2Stage2_1));
    buttons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.bObject3Stage2_1));
    buttons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.bObject4Stage2_1));
    buttons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.bObject5Stage2_1));

    Collections.shuffle(buttons);

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        //buttons.get(i).setText(objects.get(i).toString());
        buttons.get(i);
    }
```

But it's not changing the position of buttons. What am I missing in here? Any help is truly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend you to use a layout to change button orientations... a previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304368/swap-two-buttons-positions-in-tablelayout should  help

Comment: rename it on its click

Comment: @AurA i'm not going to just change the text of the button but what I want to do is change the position

Comment: @CobraAjgar I updated my post, as my plan is to change the position not the text or rename them. Because each button has a background drawble. I want to change their position.

Comment: then you need to do some extra effort with positioning....

Comment: @CobraAjgar so how do I exchange their position? Can you show me how? thanks

Comment: how do You position them now? What layout are You using?

Comment: This is my xml file for my layout: https://gist.github.com/akosijiji/80b2654ca6d6c0f009f2

Comment: dynamic add button into layout and remove it.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646929/changing-position-of-a-button

Comment: or just clean your project also.

Comment: @CobraAjgar the question you referred me to, how do I handle the shuffling of the buttons there?

Comment: @CobraAjgar absolutelayout is deprecated, but i'd still go with your first suggestion.(and inside the onclick just check their names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) to switch values between buttons You wish to move and apply them using [setLayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) method

This will allow You to switch position of 2 buttons. To shuffle them You have to prepare some algorithm to make number of switches.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) b1.getLayoutParams();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) b2.getLayoutParams();

b1.setLayoutParams(params2);
b2.setLayoutParams(params1);
```

This will work only if these button are not relative to each other.
If for example b2 was relative to b1 so it is below it You would have to set b1 to be below b1 using [addRule](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule%28int,%20int%29) method and removeRule on b2 so it is not relative to b1 any more.

for example You have in xml

```
 <Button
android:id="@+id/bObject2Stage2_1"
/*...*/
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bObject1Stage2_1" />
```

to set this rule You would write

```
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.bObject1Stage2_1);
```

Comment: can you give me tutorials so that could get me started with switching position of 2 buttons?

Comment: I don't have link to any tutorial but this is simple. Inmost cases You just have to [getLayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLayoutParams%28%29) for each of button and pass it to other one. Because You use RelativeLayout in case when these buttons will be realtive to each other You will have to edit relativeTo params before setting them to view

Comment: Check it now, hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, if you say that i have to add addRule in relativelayout, do you think I should change my layout to linearlayout?

Comment: I don't know, choose one that fits Your needs and You feel comfortable with.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29115/discussion-between-neknek-mouh-and-gustek)