# How to sort the views added dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-tablelayout

I have this master view where I have a `TableLayout` to which I add new views programmatically. The master view is given below (masterLayout.xml)

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tableLayoutActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:padding="5dp"
android:stretchColumns="*">

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/queryScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_span="2"
        android:padding="5dp">


        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/queryTableLayoutActivity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:stretchColumns="*"></TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</TableRow>
```

In the above view I add new views to `queryTableLayoutActivity` Layout. The layout to be added is given below (childLayout.xml)

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.teamtreehouse.oslist.ClassActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/activeClassActivities"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Active Class Activities"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/classNameActivity"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/abc_action_bar_stacked_tab_max_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ccc"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editClassActivity"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/deleteActivity"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/deleteActivity" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/courseNumberActivity"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/abc_action_bar_stacked_tab_max_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/classNameActivity"
            android:layout_below="@id/classNameActivity"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ccc"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/typeActivity"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/abc_action_bar_stacked_tab_max_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/classNameActivity"
            android:layout_below="@id/courseNumberActivity"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ccc"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameActivity"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/abc_action_bar_stacked_tab_max_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/classNameActivity"
            android:layout_below="@id/typeActivity"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ccc"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dueDateActivity"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/abc_action_bar_stacked_tab_max_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/classNameActivity"
            android:layout_below="@id/nameActivity"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ccc"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionActivity"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/abc_action_bar_stacked_tab_max_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/classNameActivity"
            android:layout_below="@id/dueDateActivity"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ccc"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/maxGradeActivity"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/abc_action_bar_stacked_tab_max_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/classNameActivity"
            android:layout_below="@id/descriptionActivity"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ccc"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/enterGradeActivity"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/abc_action_bar_stacked_tab_max_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/classNameActivity"
            android:layout_below="@id/maxGradeActivity"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#ccc"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/editClassActivity"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_document_edit"
            android:onClick="editListener"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/deleteActivity" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/deleteActivity"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_document_delete"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:onClick="deleteActivities"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Class Name :"
            android:id="@+id/classNameDisplay"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/classNameActivity"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/courseNumberActivity" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Course ID :"
            android:id="@+id/courseIDDisplay"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/courseNumberActivity"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/courseNumberActivity" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Course Type :"
            android:id="@+id/courseTypeDisplay"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/typeActivity"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/nameActivity" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Activity Name :"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/activityNameDisplay"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/nameActivity"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/dueDateActivity" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Due Date :"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/dueDateDisplay"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dueDateActivity"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/descriptionActivity" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Description :"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/descDisplay"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/descriptionActivity"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/maxGradeActivity" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Maximum Grade :"
            android:id="@+id/maxGradeDisplay"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/maxGradeActivity"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/maxGradeActivity" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Grade :"
            android:id="@+id/gradeDisplay"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/enterGradeActivity" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

I add the childLayout.xml to masterLayout.xml using the following code

```
TableLayout queryTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.queryTableLayoutActivity);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(
                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            String courseIDValue = c.getString(courseIdIndex);
            View newTagView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_class_activities, null);
            queryTableLayout.addView(newTagView, activeClassActivityIndex++);
```

I want to sort `childLayout` based on `dueDateActivity` field. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to bedbad's 4 steps I followed first 2 and found solution

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13913206/1815980) answer to help my situation.
This is my sort method (on button click)

```
public void sortByWeek(View v){
    queryTableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.queryTableLayoutActivity);
    int childCount = queryTableLayout.getChildCount();
    Map<View,String> map = new HashMap<View,String>();
    for(int i = 0; i<childCount;i++){
        map.put(queryTableLayout.getChildAt(i),((TextView)queryTableLayout.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.dueDateActivity)).getText().toString());
    }
    Map<View,String> sortedMap = sortByComparator(map,sort);
    ArrayList<View> viewSet = new ArrayList<>(sortedMap.keySet());
    queryTableLayout.removeAllViews();
    for(int i = 0;i<childCount;i++){
        queryTableLayout.addView(viewSet.get(i));
    }
    if(sort){
        sort = false;
    }
}

public Map<View,String> sortByComparator(Map<View,String> map,final boolean order){
    List<Map.Entry<View,String>> list = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<View,String>>(map.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<View, String>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Map.Entry<View, String> lhs, Map.Entry<View, String> rhs) {
            if(order){
                return lhs.getValue().compareTo(rhs.getValue());
            }else{
                return rhs.getValue().compareTo(lhs.getValue());
            }
        }
    });
    Map<View,String> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<View,String>();
    for(Map.Entry<View,String> entry: list){
        sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
    }
    return sortedMap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you dont want to sort layouts - you want to sort views that you inflated with certain layout. So there is no "childLayout" there is newTagView.
Your question is a form of more general question: **how to reorder n relative child views on a parent layout in certain order**. This is not about changing their sizes and positions(that's easy, you just individually because you **must** know all new params for each) this is about reordering them. This problem breaks into 4:

Note: You can't just copy-paste code, you need to make changes based on what you specifically need (like what Parameter you need and how to compare it)

### 1. Establish the current order and the order in which they need to be :

use

```
getChildCount()
```

to know number of TableLayout children, use

```
getChildAt(i)
```

to traverse and access them.
Now make the Map that will determine the transition to the new order.

```
Map<View, Parameter> map = new HashMap<Integer, Parameter>();
for(int i = 0; i < queryTableLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
map.put(queryTableLayout.getChildAt(i), 
        queryTableLayout.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.dueDateActivity)
        .getParameter());
//since newTagView should inherit all RelativeLayout methods after infation
//getParameter() - the method from TextView(dueDateActivity) you need
```

Now to make the order right you need to sort the map by parameter, 
which in Java 8 looks like

```
LinkedList<View> ordering = map.entrySet()
.stream()
.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(new Comparator<Parameter>(){
/*implement your comparator*/
})/*now when stream is sorted collect it to list*/
.collect(Collectors.toList(Map.Entry::getKey);
```

Now you have your ordering

### 2. Method to Swap

easiest way to swap views is to swap their layout params
like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16278622/5059838)

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) b1.getLayoutParams();
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) b2.getLayoutParams();

b1.setLayoutParams(params2);
b2.setLayoutParams(params1);
```

Make a method void swap(View A, View B){...} which will work for your RelativeLayout View with that code.

### 3. Do the thing.

```
for(int i = 0; i < queryTableLayout.getChildCount(); i++)
swap(queryTableLayout.getChildAt(i), ordering.get(i));
```

---

If you want them add dynamically in already sorted place that is **much easier** You just need to get the right pos, and params like in (1)
and [use](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int%29)

```
public void addView (View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)
```

Comment: Well although I tried a different solution this answer gave me a good start to think in that perspective. Thanks a lot.